# Java Ambiguous method when a method has a generic parameter and other method has a generic lambda

Tags: java, generics, lambda

Consider the following:

```
    public void run() {
        run(o -> {});
    }

    //replace CharSequence with whatever except Object
    public <E extends CharSequence> void run(E e) {
    }
    public <E extends CharSequence> void run(Consumer<E> e){
    }
```

The compiler complains about `java reference to run is ambiguous` even that the parameter passed is clearly a lambda and only one of the two methods is lambda

The question is why this is happening? Is it a bug? what should the signature be replaced with to achieve the same behavior?

Extra:
IntelliJ says (the class `Main` does not matter):

```
Ambiguous method call. Both
run(CharSequence) in Main and
run(Consumer<CharSequence>) in Main match
```

Note:
replacing `CharSequence` with ANYTHING except `java.lang.Object` will produce the same issue!

Also Note:
It does not matter even if the two generics are different and don't relate to each other! As long as they are not `java.lang.Object`.

So, this will not compile ether:

```
    public void run() {
        run(o -> {});
    }
    public <E extends ArrayList> void run(E e) {
    }
    public <E extends String> void run(Consumer<E> e){
    }
```

Comment: `The same behaviour` statement includes: No casting in the parameter assignment, Still using generic type, retaining the same name and the same class

Comment: I get a different compile error, which is `The target type of this expression must be a functional interface`. (Java 11.0.6)

Comment: "The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other one without a compile-time error." Neither method is more specific by this definition, so they are ambiguous.

Comment: Yes, I got that too.

Comment: But I think it is definitely obvious that a Consumer is not a CharSequence

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Comment: Nor a CharSequence can be declared as a lambda

Comment: I use java 8....

Comment: If we remove (comment out) `public <E extends CharSequence> void run(Consumer<E> e){ }` and only leave `public <E extends CharSequence> void run(E e) {}` code will not allow `run(o -> {});` to compile which suggests that compiler now doesn't consider `<E extends CharSequence> void run(E e)` as valid possibility. Interesting question ++.

Comment: What if you have `interface Sample extends CharSequence {
        default int length() {
            return 1;
        }

        default char charAt(int index) {
            return 'c';
        }


        default CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
            return "";
        }

        void sample();
    }` ?

Comment: *"even that the parameter passed is clearly a lambda and only one of the two methods is lambda"* - that is incorrect. None of them is a lambda. You have a fundamental misconception of lambdas. A lambda creates an instance of an interface, hence it can be used everywhere where an ordinary (functional) interface is expected. `Consumer` is an interface and `E` can be one as well.

Answer (score 1):

> Nor a CharSequence can be declared as a lambda

Have a look.

```
interface WeirdCharSequence extends CharSequence {
  default int length() { return 0; }
  default char charAt(int index) { return 0; }
  default CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) { return null; }

  void accept(CharSequence i); 
}
```

proves it can

```
WeirdCharSequence charSequence = o -> {};
run(charSequence);
```

`o -> {}` could mean many things, and there is not enough context to figure out what exactly the lambda represents. You can always help the compiler out by explicitly declaring the desired type.

```
this.<CharSequence>run(o -> {});
```

or

```
Consumer<CharSequence> consumer = o -> {};
run(consumer);
```

or (personally less preferable)

```
run((Consumer<CharSequence>)o -> {});
```

It could be that the compiler sees `E` as a type that is both a `Consumer<CharSequence>` and `CharSequence`.

```
class ReallyWeirdCharSequence implements Consumer<CharSequence>, CharSequence {
  public void accept(CharSequence i) { }
  public int length() { return 0; }
  public char charAt(int index) { return 0; }
  public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) { return null; }
}
```

Comment: You took my statement literally lol. I mean You cannot create a lambda cast to CharSequence. Anyway CharSequence is just an example

Comment: further question, how does `this.<CharSequence>run(o -> {});` help and why not   `this.run((Consumer<CharSequence>) a -> {});`?

Comment: A lambda can be used everywhere where an ordinary interface is expected (as long as its functional).

Comment: The thing is even if you replace `CharSequence` with any `class` like `String`, it wont fix the issue

Comment: @Naman I think both should help as they both clearly state what is coming (like `Consumer<CharSequence> consumer = o -> {}; run(consumer);`), I just don't like casts

Comment: @Naman it helps because it resolves the type `E` unambiguously, while in the case of `run(o -> {})` the compiler comes up with a vague `E` (I don't know what it is, apparently not just `CharSequence`) that is equally acceptable for both signatures

Comment: @LSaferSE any subclass of CharSequence should help there, I tried with CharSequence, String, StringBuffer

Answer (score 0):

After some investigations, I realized that it is a bug in the java language.

Try that your self:

```
    public void run() {
        run(o -> {});
    }
    public <E extends Class> void run(E e) {
    }
    public void run(Consumer e) {
    }
```

Or:

```
    public void run() {
        run(o -> {});
    }
    public <E extends Class> void run(E e) {
    }
    public <E extends Integer> void run(Consumer<E> e) {
    }
```

Even that the parameters of both functions don't relate to each other. Somehow the java compiler thinks that they are.

In conclusion, creating a method with a generic parameter will make the method valid as a method that accepts lambda expression.

Answer (score -2):

Guessing now, but everything has a toString method and it's kinda common to implicitly convert things to strings by having the compiler implicitly call it for you. String is of course an inheritor of CharSequence. So the compiler could be complaining that it can't decide between:

```
run((CharSequence)(o -> {}).toString());
```

and

```
run((Consumer<CharSequence>)(o -> {}));
```

Comment: What about if the parameter is an Exception/Number or basically anything else? I wrote CharSequence as an example, Actually, I faced the issue with Throwable

Comment: *"the compiler implicitly call it for you"* - the compiler does not implicitly call `toString` for you. If you are thinking about `System.out.println(myObject)`, the `toString` call is explicitly implemented in the `println` method.

Comment: This answer is simply wrong. The compiler only calls `toString()` implicitly in string concatenation.